# What's the best way to switch between https and and http with my RKObjectManager in Restkit?

Tags: ios, restkit

What's the best way to switch between having a http and https base url for RKObjectManager.  Should I let the shared manager be set to the http base url and then new up a whole new instance or RKOjbectManager for https requests?  Are there any pitfalls or gotchas I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did just the same thing -  i keep three instances of the RKObjectManager (http, https and the third one with different baseUrl to interface with some portions of legacy API) and it works like a charm.

Comment: when creating multiple RKObjectManagers, how do you call out a request on one specific object manager with the desired baseURL if it is not a shared singleton?

Comment: i wrap them in my custom singleton. The singleton is initialized when app starts (in delegate).